# How to get multiresult with multicondition in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I need help to solve this.

Hopefully someone can giving me advices.

For a sample, I've got data like :

```
                            PROCLIB.MARCH                                1
                          First 10 Rows Only

  Flight     Date  Depart  Orig  Dest     Miles   Boarded  Capacity
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
  114     01MAR94    7:10  LGA   LAX       2475       172       210
  202     01MAR94   10:43  LGA   ORD        740       151       210
  219     01MAR94    9:31  LGA   LON       3442       198       250
  622     01MAR94   12:19  LGA   FRA       3857       207       250
  132     01MAR94   15:35  LGA   YYZ        366       115       178
  271     01MAR94   13:17  LGA   PAR       3635       138       250
  302     01MAR94   20:22  LGA   WAS        229       105       180
  114     02MAR94    7:10  LGA   LAX       2475       119       210
  202     02MAR94   10:43  LGA   ORD        740       120       210
  219     02MAR94    9:31  LGA   LON       3442       147       250
```

and i have condition for ('LAX,ORD'), 'LAX','LON','YYZ',('PAR,LON,FRA'),'FRA' ...AND ELSE

What should i do with that data to show report as that condition in SQL?

Parameter that I made is

```
 Dest like @dest -> (from table condition(('LAX, ORD'), 'LAX','LON',('PAR,LON,FRA'),'FRA',..etc)) +'%' 
 And Date like @date + '%' 
 And Depart like @depart + '%'
```

If I choose `'LAX'` as `@dest`, then only `'LAX'` will show

If I choose `'LAX,ORD'` as `@dest`, then only `'LAX'` and `'ORD'` will show

Please I need help, advice and suggestion for this.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some sample result?

Comment: Can you also provide a sample query that you wrote?

Comment: @Bobi Aria : Use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @BobiAria: You have to improve your question, this way noone really understands it

Answer (score 0):

If your  `@dest` value is 'LAX,ORD', one query that will solve your solution is

```
 select *
 from PROCLIB.MARCH
 where dest in ('LAX','ORD')
```

To parameterise that, you need it to become a table.

```
 Dest
 ====
 LAX
 ORD
```

and the query becomes

```
 select *     
 from PROCLIB.MARCH
 where dest in (select Dest from @DestTable)
```

If you want to pass `@dest` as a string parameter, then you need to split it somehow into a table. A search for SQL split function will give a number of options.

If your query is encapsulated in a stored procedure, a better method is to pass the values as a table valued parameter. See http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/